# In Firefox, what exactly does "Reset Firefox" do?

Tags: firefox, backup, troubleshooting, firefox-extensions, reset

What exactly does the "Reset Firefox" function do in Firefox? (Firefox->Help->Troubleshooting Information->Reset Firefox) It says that things get reset to their default state -- is there a precise list of things that get reset?

I've been using the same Firefox profile for almost two years, using it across version upgrades. It was recommended that I do a "Reset Firefox", purely for good measure, having amassed a profile across so many versions.

While I'm OK to do this, I don't want to lose my extensions, preferences, history, etc. I've fully backed all of these up with/through extensions "FEBE" and "OPIE". But I'm wondering if, after doing a "Reset Firefox", my restoring of things from my old profile are merely going to bring the outdated/cluttered garbage back to the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Reset Firefox – easily fix most problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) and [Reset Your Firefox](http://blog.mozilla.org/theden/2012/06/13/resetfirefox/) articles:

> What does the reset feature do?
>
> All of your Firefox settings and personal information are stored in
>   your profile folder. The reset feature works by creating a new profile
>   folder for you while saving your most important data.
>
> Firefox will try to keep the following data:
>
> - Bookmarks
> - Browsing history
> - Passwords
> - Cookies
> - Web form auto-fill information
>
> The following items and settings will be restored or removed:
>
> - Extensions and themes: Although they can be incredibly helpful, some extensions and themes can cause problems. If you need to
>     reinstall important extensions, see [Find and install add-ons to add
>     features to Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-install-add-ons-add-features-to-firefox) for help.
> - Open tabs, windows and tab groups: The reset process will close all open websites. Since your bookmarks and browsing history are saved
>     you should still be able to easily return to your favorite sites. See
>     [Where can I find my bookmarks?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-bookmarks-to-save-and-organize-websites#w_where-can-i-find-my-bookmarks) and [Awesome Bar - Find your bookmarks,
>     history and tabs when you type in the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs) for more info. Also,
>     since your [cookies](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cookies-information-websites-store-on-your-computer) are saved, you shouldn't be logged out of any
>     websites you were logged in to before the reset.
> - Site-specific preferences, search engines, personal dictionary, download history, DOM storage, security certificate settings, security
>     device settings, download actions, plugin MIME types, toolbar
>     customizations and user styles are also not saved. See the [Profiles -
>     Where Firefox stores your bookmarks, passwords and other user data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)
>     article for more information about these.

Comment: So does that mean it's essentially just creating a new profile and then attempting to restore a few things? Is "creating a new profile folder" the equivalent of simply creating a new profile?

Comment: I think that's what it essentially does..

Comment: @Coldblackice: Yes, that's what it does - it creates a new profile and only copies the essential things over. Any breakage or slowness stays in the old profile.